AES-128-ECB decryption "fails" due to padding after migrating from OpenSSL 1.0.2b to 3.3.0
I have a test program that works when linking to OpenSSL 1.0.2b but fails with OpenSSL 3.0.0 and OpenSSL 3.3.0. I believe the issue is on the encryption side because the decryption programmatically succeeds (returns no error) but the plaintext still contains padding.
If the input length is divisible by the block size, a block of padding with the expected value is added to the recovered plaintext (but not stripped after decryption). The plaintext is a full block longer than expected with a predictable extra block. The expected value is always the count of padded bytes, so for a full block of padding you get 16 bytes of 0x10 (16).
E.g.: plaintext ends on an even block with:
...                      0x01 0x02 0x03
Recovered plaintext ends with:
...                      0x01 0x02 0x03
0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10
0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10
If the input length is not divisible by the block size, the second to last block of the plaintext is padded with the final plaintext (e.g. if there was 1 byte not divisible by the block size and that byte was set to 0x31, you see an entire block of 0x31) followed by another block of padding with the expected value (still, not stripped after decryption). The plaintext is more than one block (but less than two full blocks) longer than expected and is unpredictable without knowing the original plaintext length.
E.g.: plaintext ends on an incomplete block with:
0x01
Recovered plaintext ends with that block padded out plus the normal padding block:
0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01
0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01
0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10
0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10
I've tried explicitly enabling padding, explicitly disabling padding, and pre-fetching the cipher context, and nothing seems to make a difference. With padding disabled, I don't get the full block of 0x10 at the end but I still get leftover padding when the input size is not divisible by the block size.
The key is 16 bytes (128 bits) and the input and output buffers are sized at least 2 blocks larger than necessary.
I can't believe I'm the only one seeing this unless everyone was able to rid themselves of ECB (I need to decrypt files out in the wild that already exist with this, though).
Here's the encryption:
// Encrypt data_length bytes of data into enc_data using key
EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx{EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()};
if ( !ctx ) { 
    return -1;
}

EVP_CIPHER* cipher{EVP_CIPHER_fetch(nullptr, "AES-128-ECB", nullptr)};
if ( !cipher ) {
    return -1;
}

// Explicitly enable padding - doesn't seem to matter
int padding{1};
OSSL_PARAM params[2];
params[0] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_int(OSSL_CIPHER_PARAM_PADDING,&padding);
params[0] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_end();

if ( EVP_EncryptInit_ex2(ctx,cipher,key,nullptr,params) != 1 ) {
    return -1;
}

int input_ptr{0};
int output_ptr{0};
// Encrypt until the output_ptr meets or exceeds the input data_length
while ( output_ptr < data_length ) {
    int this_enc_len{0};
    if ( EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx,reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(enc_data) + output_ptr,&this_enc_len,reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + input_ptr, data_length - input_ptr) != 1 ) {
        return -1;
    }
    input_ptr += this_enc_len;
    output_ptr += this_enc_len;
}

int final_enc_len{0};
if ( EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx,reintrepret_cast<unsigned char*>(enc_data) + output_ptr,&final_enc_len) != 1 ) {
    return -1;
}
output_ptr += final_enc_len;

// Cleanup omitted for brevity
return output_ptr;

Padding is always added whether explicitly enabled or disabled. Input sizes which are evenly divisible by the block size are not padded; otherwise they are padded out to an even 16-byte length.
Decryption is similar:
// Decrypt data_length bytes of data into dec_data using key
EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx{EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()};
if ( !ctx ) { 
    return -1;
}

EVP_CIPHER* cipher{EVP_CIPHER_fetch(nullptr, "AES-128-ECB", nullptr)};
if ( !cipher ) {
    return -1;
}

// Explicitly enable padding - doesn't seem to matter here either
int padding{1};
OSSL_PARAM params[2];
params[0] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_int(OSSL_CIPHER_PARAM_PADDING,&padding);
params[0] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_end();

if ( EVP_DecryptInit_ex2(ctx,cipher,key,nullptr,params) != 1 ) {
    return -1;
}

int input_ptr{0};
int output_ptr{0};
while ( output_ptr < data_length ) {
    int this_enc_len{0};
    if ( EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx,reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(dec_data) + output_ptr,&this_enc_len,reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + input_ptr, data_length - input_ptr) != 1 ) {
        return -1;
    }
    input_ptr += this_enc_len;
    output_ptr += this_enc_len;
}

int final_enc_len{0};
if ( EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx,reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(dec_data) + output_ptr,&final_enc_len) != 1 ) {
    return -1;
}
output_ptr += final_enc_len;

// Cleanup again omitted for brevity
return output_ptr;

Has anyone else seen this? Have you come up with a solution or workaround?

Calling EVP_EncryptUpdate in a loop like that doesn't look right. It will encrypt all the data it can in one call, which in this case is always data_length. So the update of the pointers is wrong and there is no need for a loop. I didn't look but I assume something similar is wrong with the decrypt side.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk the loop is required for most block encryption algorithms if I'm not mistaken. Subsequent calls encrypt incomplete blocks at the end not divisible by the block size. Removing the loop causes the call to EVP_EncryptFinal_ex to fail consistently.

Multiple EVP_EncryptUpdate() calls are intended to pass different plaintexts (e.g. the chunks of a long plaintext). In your loop, however, parts of the same plaintext are passed multiple times (more precisely, the last plaintext block (if incomplete) is written to the buffer multiple times), which is why the plaintext is extended. For me, the code only works correctly without the while-loop, i.e. with exactly one EVP_EncryptUpdate() call (so that the plaintext is written to the buffer without partial repeats) and one EVP_EncryptFinal_ex() call (which pads).

You can verify this using a simple example: For the plaintext Hello, the loop is run through four times, i.e. EVP_EncryptUpdate() is called four times and the plaintext Hello is written to the buffer each time. Finally, EVP_EncryptFinal_ex() pads, so that in the end HelloHelloHelloHello plus 12 0x0c padding bytes have been encrypted.

If you decrypt the ciphertext generated in this way with a working logic, e.g. with CyberChef, this becomes evident, s. here.

No, this is not right semantically. You encrypt using ECB + padding until you've passed all input bytes to the method. You should definitely decouple the loop from the output size created. The final call will add the padding, so you can get stuck in that loop. During decryption you have the same issue but worse as the output size (i.e. the plaintext size) will never surpass the bigger ciphertext size. And in the end the padding should add 1 to n bytes, with n the block size in bytes (i.e. 1 to 16 for AES).
Let's create a mental picture (which skips some obvious tricks to speed up multi-block encryption). What happens is that you pass bytes to a buffer during "update", and if a full block is in the buffer then it will be encrypted. When all bytes have been put into the buffer then there are zero to n - 1 bytes in the buffer. Now the padding is added into the buffer and the last block is encrypted when the call to the "final" method is made.
This means that the last bytes may never be output before you're calling final. So even though the ciphertext is always larger than the plaintext (due to the block boundary & padding) the "update" method may never "see" this condition, as the buffer is still holding the data for the final block.
Similarly, during decryption you'd pass all data into the buffer during update. If the buffer is full it cannot be directly returned, as the data may well be the padding, which should not be returned. This is why you will only get back the final data during the call to "final" as that's the only way that the decryption routine knows that it has been given the final block with the padding. So funny enough the implementation has to buffer more during decryption.
TL;DR: just focus on the bytes you put into the algorithm implementation and then call the final method, preparing for some extra bytes that it may return.
If all the data is is in a single continuous buffer and a large enough output buffer is available then a single call to "update" and "final" should be all that is necessary.

Addendum: it was mentioned that the function only returns the number of output bytes. However, this is the case because the number of output bytes is the only unknown. The function will precisely encrypt the number of bytes that is given to it.
From the documentation:

EVP_EncryptUpdate()
Encrypts inl bytes from the buffer in and writes the encrypted version to out. The pointers out and in may point to the same location, in which case the encryption will be done in-place. If out and in point to different locations, the two buffers must be disjoint, otherwise the operation might fail or the outcome might be undefined.
This function can be called multiple times to encrypt successive blocks of data. The amount of data written depends on the block alignment of the encrypted data. For most ciphers and modes, the amount of data written can be anything from zero bytes to (inl + cipher_block_size - 1) bytes. For wrap cipher modes, the amount of data written can be anything from zero bytes to (inl + cipher_block_size) bytes. For stream ciphers, the amount of data written can be anything from zero bytes to inl bytes. Thus, the buffer pointed to by out must contain sufficient room for the operation being performed. The actual number of bytes written is placed in outl.

It may be that the code has been over-thought; the number of bytes that are received processed is known exactly in advance by inl. If they are already put into the output buffer is the only unknown.

I'm not entirely sure I understand your suggestion. The EVP_EncryptUpdate only tells me how many bytes it has encrypted, int* outl. It does not tell me how many bytes of the input buffer have been encrypted. So I can call EVP_EncryptUpdate once which results in a failed call to EVP_EncryptFinal_ex, or call EVP_EncryptUpdate until it stops advancing the outl. As coded, the loop executes once for inputs of sizes divisible by the block size, and more than once for other input sizes, but never loops infinitely. Without the loops, both "final" calls return an error.

It doesn't need to "tell [me] how many bytes in of the input buffer" have been encrypted because that is known, it is exactly inl bytes. The way that I've described is true for almost any cryptographic API which uses an update / final way of handling the data. If the "final" returns an error then it is because of another bug in the code or, of course, input data. I've updated my answer. You should debug that code and post a new question if you get stuck doing that.

I updated the code and comment below to indicate failure without the loops. After implementing my own PKCS7 padding outside of OpenSSL it works every time so I think the issue is with enabling the padding. This worked as initially written on older versions of OpenSSL for probably close to 10 years.

I'm rolling back your question as the comments and my answer don't make sense with the new code. As indicated please post a new question. It is very unlikely that it is impossible to get this to work without OpenSSL performing the padding, so something is still wrong.
